# How do I construct a parse tree from a series of S-expression tokens in Prolog?

Tags: parsing, prolog, grammar, dcg, parse-tree

I'm curious about Prolog as a parser, so I'm making a little Lisp front-end. I have already made a tokenizer, which you can see here:

```
base_tokenize([], Buffer, [Buffer]).
base_tokenize([Char | Chars], Buffer, Tokens) :-
    (Char = '(' ; Char = ')') ->
        base_tokenize(Chars, '', Tail_Tokens),
        Tokens = [Buffer, Char | Tail_Tokens];

    Char = ' ' ->
        base_tokenize(Chars, '', Tail_Tokens),
        Tokens = [Buffer | Tail_Tokens];

    atom_concat(Buffer, Char, New_Buffer),
    base_tokenize(Chars, New_Buffer, Tokens).

filter_empty_blank([], []).
filter_empty_blank([Head | Tail], Result) :-
    filter_empty_blank(Tail, Tail_Result),
    ((Head = [] ; Head = '') ->
        Result = Tail_Result;
        Result = [Head | Tail_Result]).

tokenize(Expr, Tokens) :-
    atom_chars(Expr, Chars),
    base_tokenize(Chars, '', Dirty_Tokens),
    filter_empty_blank(Dirty_Tokens, Tokens).
```

I now have a new challenge: construct a parse tree from this. First, I tried making one without a grammar, but that turned out really messy. So I'm using DCGs. Wikipedia's page on [it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar#:%7E:text=They%20are%20called%20definite%20clause,definite%20clauses%20are%20considered%20DCGs.) is not very clear - especially the portion **Parsing with DCGs**. Maybe someone can give me a clearer idea of how I would construct a tree? I was very happy to know that Prolog's lists are untyped, so it's a bit easier now that no sum types are needed. I'm just really confused about inputs to grammar clauses like `sentence(s(NP,VP))` or `verb(v(eats))` (on the Wiki), why the arguments have such abstruse names, and how I can get started with my parser without too much hassle.

```
expr --> [foo].
expr --> list.

seq --> expr, seq.
seq --> expr.

list --> ['('], seq, [')'].
```

Comment: A nice intro to dcg,  https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg . It has a good tree construction example.

Comment: Yeah that Wikipedia page is not excellent as is the custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a beginning: Parsing a LISP list-of-atom, which at first is unstructured list-of-token:

```
List = [ '(', '(', foo, bar, ')', baz ')' ].
```

First, just accept it.

Write down the grammar directly:

```
so_list         --> ['('], so_list_content, [')'].

so_list_content --> [].
so_list_content --> so_atom, so_list_content.
so_list_content --> so_list, so_list_content.

so_atom         --> [X], { \+ member(X,['(',')']),atom(X) }.
```

Add some test cases (is there [plunit](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) in GNU Prolog?)

```
:- begin_tests(accept_list).

test(1,[fail])        :- phrase(so_list,[]).
test(2,[true,nondet]) :- phrase(so_list,['(',')']).
test(3,[true,nondet]) :- phrase(so_list,['(',foo,')']).
test(4,[true,nondet]) :- phrase(so_list,['(',foo,'(',bar,')',')']).
test(5,[true,nondet]) :- phrase(so_list,['(','(',bar,')',foo,')']).
test(6,[fail])        :- phrase(so_list,['(',foo,'(',bar,')']).

:- end_tests(accept_list).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: accept_list ...... done
% All 6 tests passed
true.
```

Cool. Looks like we can accept lists-of-tokens.

Now build a parse tree. This is done by growing a Prolog term through parameters of the "DCG predicates". The term (or multiple terms) in the head collect the terms (or multiple terms) appearing in the body into a larger structure, quite naturally. Once the terminal tokens are reached, the structure starts to fill up with actual content:

```
so_list(list(Stuff))   --> ['('], so_list_content(Stuff), [')'].

so_list_content([])        --> [].
so_list_content([A|Stuff]) --> so_atom(A), so_list_content(Stuff).
so_list_content([L|Stuff]) --> so_list(L), so_list_content(Stuff).

so_atom(X) --> [X], { \+ member(X,['(',')']),atom(X) }.
```

Yup, tests (move the expected Result out of the test head because the visual noise is too much)

```
:- begin_tests(parse_list).

test(1,[fail]) :-
   phrase(so_list(_),[]).

test(2,[true(L==Result),nondet]) :-
   phrase(so_list(L),['(',')']),
   Result = list([]).
   
test(3,[true(L==Result),nondet]) :-
   phrase(so_list(L),['(',foo,')']),
   Result = list([foo]).
   
test(4,[true(L==Result),nondet]) :-
   phrase(so_list(L),['(',foo,'(',bar,')',')']),
   Result = list([foo,list([bar])]).
   
test(5,[true(L==Result),nondet]) :-
   phrase(so_list(L),['(','(',bar,')',foo,')']),
   Result = list([list([bar]),foo]).
   
test(6,[fail]) :-
   phrase(so_list(_),['(',foo,'(',bar,')']).

:- end_tests(parse_list).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: parse_list ...... done
% All 6 tests passed
true.
```

Comment: I can't find `plunit` for GNU Prolog, but there's probably some other unit testing system out there. Actually, I already figured out how to verify whether a sequence of tokens is valid - constructing the tree is what's tripping me up. Could you elaborate on that step?

Comment: This was so helpful! Thank you.